# Focal length, sensor size and field of view in digital photography

Tags: lens, focal-length, field-of-view

For a robotics project, I've been testing two cameras

```
1)ELP USBFHD04H, sensor AR0330, 1/3 inch
2)ELP USBFHD06H, sensor Sony IMX322, 1/2.9 inch
```

Besides, I've been testing different lenses, all of them using the same M12 mounts:

```
a)Generic 2.1mm focal distance
b)Runcam RC21 1/3 2.1mm
c)Generic 150° HFOV
d)Generic 170° HFOV
e)Generic 180° HFOV
```

I'm aiming to have a decent FOV. After trying all combinations, I still haven't been able to understand how exactly FOV depends on other factors. My results so far:

```
1 combined with a,b,c,d -> Really narrow FOV, around 90°. Not really much difference between them
1xe -> Wide, more than 170°
2xa -> Narrow, around 90°
2xb -> Wide, around 160°
2 combined with c,d,e -> Wide, aprox. corresponding with what is marketed.
```

So, after some testing, the results are not really consistent. I would really appreciate some insights. Thanks

Comment: Please provide more information about the lenses (i.e., specs, or links to their info or sales sites). Are you sure the stated FOV is _horizontal_?

Answer (score 2):

Math using Excel to find angle of view

The image sensor dimensions = D
The focal length = F

Focal length mm  =  50mm

Height format mm  = 24mm            27.0°   vertical angle of view

Length format mm  = 36mm            39.6°   horizontal angle of view

diagonal mm =       43.27mm     46.8°   diagonal angle of view

=((ATAN((F/2/D)))*180/PI()*2

Hope this helps!